# jQuery find antecedent?

Tags: jquery

When I want to find a child of an object I can use `children()`; when I want to find an object inside another object, not necessarily it's child, I can use `find()`. If I want to find a parent, I use `parent()`, but if I want to find an antecedent, not knowing if it's parent grandparent, grand-grandparent, how can I do it?

I'll give you an example: I am building a plugin that is to be applied to some 'input:text'.

In the end, I need to do something to the form that holds them. But sometimes, the text-boxes will be directly inside the form, or they can be inside an unordered list or inside a table.

Am I able to refer to the form in a general way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `closest()` method:

```
$('input:text').change(
function(){
    var ancestorFormElement = $(this).closest('form');
    // do stuff.
});
```

```js
$('input:text').change(function() {
  var ancestorFormElement = $(this).closest('form');

  ancestorFormElement.addClass('hasInputChanged');
});
```

```css
form {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 1em;
}
form.hasInputChanged {
  border-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Simple demo</legend>
    <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/L9sg06hq/), for experimentation or development.

Or, instead, you could simply use the DOM approach which associates the `<form>` element with its descendant form-elements (`<input />`, `<textarea>`, `<select>` etc):

```
$('input:text').change(function() {
  var ancestorFormElement = this.form;

  // because 'this.form' returns a DOM node, it
  // must be converted to a jQuery object in 
  // order to utilise jQuery methods:
  $(ancestorFormElement).addClass('hasInputChanged');
});
```

```js
$('input:text').change(function() {
  var ancestorFormElement = this.form;

  $(ancestorFormElement).addClass('hasInputChanged');
});
```

```css
form {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 1em;
}
form.hasInputChanged {
  border-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Simple demo</legend>
    <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/L9sg06hq/1/), for experimentation or development.

Further, because I'd strongly suspect that you want the changes – whatever they may be – to revert should the 'change' be undone, I'd suggest the following approach:

```
$('input:text').change(function() {
  var ancestorFormElement = this.form;

  // here we use the 'toggleClass(<class-name>, <switch>)'
  // method; where the 'switch' returns a Boolean true/false
  // if it evaluates to true then the class-name is added
  // and if it evaluates to false then the class-name is
  // removed:
  $(ancestorFormElement).toggleClass('hasInputChanged', this.value !== this.defaultValue);
});
```

```js
$('input:text').change(function() {
  var ancestorFormElement = this.form;

  $(ancestorFormElement).toggleClass('hasInputChanged', this.value !== this.defaultValue);
});
```

```css
form {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 1em;
}
form.hasInputChanged {
  border-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Simple demo</legend>
    <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/L9sg06hq/2/), for experimentation or development.

Also, it's entirely possible to delegate the `change` event-handler to the `<form>` element itself, using the `on()`:

```
$('form').on('change', function(e) {

  // here 'e' is the event-object passed to the
  // event-handling function; 'e.target' is the
  // element that received the initiating event:
  var changedEl = e.target;

  $(this).toggleClass('hasInputChanged', changedEl.value !== changedEl.defaultValue);
});
```

```js
$('form').on('change', function(e) {
  var changedEl = e.target;

  $(this).toggleClass('hasInputChanged', changedEl.value !== changedEl.defaultValue);
});
```

```css
form {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 1em;
}
form.hasInputChanged {
  border-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Simple demo</legend>
    <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/L9sg06hq/3/), for experimentation or development.

It's also possible to pass a selector into the `on()` method to specify the elements that should initiate the given event (here the 'change' event) to
trigger the event-handling bound to the ancestor:

```
// here we pass the selector, 'input[type=text]' to the
// method, which restricts the event-handling to only
// those events originating with <input> elements whose
// 'type' attribute is equal to 'text':
$('form').on('change', 'input[type=text]', function(e) {

  $(this).toggleClass('hasInputChanged', changedEl.value !== changedEl.defaultValue);
});
```

```js
$('form').on('change', 'input[type=text]', function(e) {
  var ancestorFormElement = this.form;

  $(ancestorFormElement).toggleClass('hasInputChanged', this.value !== this.defaultValue);
});
```

```css
form {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 1em;
}
form.hasInputChanged {
  border-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Simple demo</legend>
    <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/L9sg06hq/4/), for experimentation or development.

And, finally, a plain JavaScript means of accomplishing the same behaviour:

```
// defining a named function to handle the
// event-handling, the 'event' argument is
// passed automagically from the
// addEventListener() method (below):
function changeHandler(event) {

  // 'this' is the element to which
  // event-handler was bound (again
  // automagically passed from
  // addEventListener()):
  var form = this,
    changed = event.target;

  // here we use the Element.classList API; which
  // works much as toggleClass() does, adding the
  // supplied class-name if the switch that follows
  // evaluates to true, removes it if the switch
  // evaluates to false:
  form.classList.toggle('hasInputChanged', changed.value !== changed.defaultValue);

}

// retrieving the <form> element using
// document.querySelector(), which returns
// the first element in the document that
// matches the CSS selector passed to the
// function:
var formElement = document.querySelector('form');

// using addEventListener to bind the named 
// function (changeHandler) as the event-
// handler for the 'change' event:
formElement.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
```

```js
function changeHandler(event) {
  var form = this,
    changed = event.target;

  form.classList.toggle('hasInputChanged', changed.value !== changed.defaultValue);

}

var formElement = document.querySelector('form');

formElement.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
```

```css
form {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 1em;
}
form.hasInputChanged {
  border-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Simple demo</legend>
    <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/L9sg06hq/5/), for experimentation or development.

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute selectors](http://w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is, as it isn't very clear as it is.

I think you may be looking for the jQuery [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) function though.

Example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="content"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`$("#content").parents("table")` should get the `<table>` element.

Comment: you're right about the clarity of the question, but i have the flu, and am not able to articulate very well. i'm going to check it out. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/parents/ and http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/